# How to delete and recreate pods using yaml file in kubernetes

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I have a yaml file which I can use to create pods. I am using the dashboard so I can simply select yaml file and it will create pods. Pod will start the container and container will run the docker image. So now lets say I have done some changes in the docker image and want to deploy it again. For this, I will delete the already running pod and will upload the yaml file.

Instead of deleting and uploading yaml file again, is there any keyword available which will delete the already running pod/deployment and will recreate it.

Thanks

Comment: You can try the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848606/kubernetes-old-pod-not-being-deleted-after-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember the StackOverflow question where I first saw this method, but here it is again:

`kubectl --namespace thenamespace get pod thepod -o yaml | kubectl replace --save-config -f -`

You can do that with all k8s resources.

Comment: A word of caution about using this is if you are following a declarative deployment method (i.e. using `kubectl apply`), the use of `replace` will not write the `last-applied-configuration` annotation unless you add the `--save-config` option. A comparison of imperative and declarative methods is available at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/overview/

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this for development you might get away with

```
containers:
- image: my/app:dev
  imagePullPolicy: Always
```

With this, whenever your pod is recreated, you will get fresh image version.

That said, you need to use something like Deployment to have a pod restarted automaticaly, and then you can just `kubectl delete my-pod-xxxxx-yyy` to wipe old one and in few sec get the fresh, current one.

For prod, don't do that please. Just use tagged images and apply changed image to your Deployment with `kubectl apply -f my.yaml` or preferably something like Helm (but that is more complicated topic for starters)

Comment: Is image cached in cluster?

Answer (score 1):

kubectl replace --force -f podfile.yaml